# Artin's Algebra Book Problem:Prove that splitting fields of $x^3+ex+6$ over $Q(e)$ and $x^3+\pi x+6$ over $Q(\pi)$ are isomorphic.

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Assume that $\pi$ and $e$ are transcendental. Let $K$ be the splitting field of $f(x)=x^{3} + \pi x + 6$ over $F = Q(\pi)$

(a) Prove that  $[K : F] = 6$.

(b) Prove that $K$ is isomorphic to the splitting field of $x^3 +ex+6$ over $Q(e)$

It's clear that $f$ has only one real root and also as $\pi$ is transcedental over $Q$ therefore $f$ is irreducible over $Q(\pi)$,which in particular implies that $[K:F]$=6.

Any ideas about part $(b)$ ?

Comment: Well, $x^3+ex+6$ is not a polynomial over $\mathbb Q(\pi)$, so how can it have a splitting field?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews typos edited now!

Comment: Is is the same polynomial with $\pi$ replaced by $e$ and they have the same properties ;where is the problem?

Comment: @learnmore It's not clear what you are trying to say as your sentence starts with "Is".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $e$ and $\pi$ are transcendental, both $\mathbb Q(e)$ and $\mathbb Q(\pi)$ are isomorphic to the rational function field $\mathbb Q(t)$. If we let $\phi: \mathbb Q(e) \to \mathbb Q(\pi)$ be a field isomorphism, then $\phi$ induces an isomorphism of polynomial rings $\phi: \mathbb Q(e)[x] \to \mathbb Q(\pi)[x]$. Under this isomorphism, we have $\phi(x^3+ex+6)= x^3+\pi x+6$, and in this situation, $\phi$ extends to an isomorphism of the splitting fields of the two polynomials; e.g., see section 13.4 of Dummit and Foote, *Abstract Algebra*:

> Theorem 27. Let $\phi:F \to F'$ be an isomorphism of fields. Let $f(x)\in F[x]$ be
>   a polynomial and let $f'(x) \in F'[x]$ be the polynomial obtained by
>   applying $\phi$ to the coefficients of $f(x)$. Let $E$ be a splitting
>   field for $f(x)$ over $F$ and let $E'$ be a splitting field for
>   $f'(x)$ over $F'$. Then the isomorphism $\phi$ extends to an
>   isomorphism $\sigma: E \to E'$, i.e., $\sigma$ restricted to $F$ is
>   the isomorphism $\phi$.

Comment: Thank you for telling me this theorem !

Comment: I don't understand how  $[K:F]=6$?Can you explain ?